# Get variables in PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Say I pass data to a partial view like this

```
@Html.Partial("_LandingPage_CaseStudiesList", new { TrackAction = "Case Study Click", CaseStudies = Model.CaseStudies  })
```

How do I then get the data in the partial?

I have tried `Model["TrackAction"]` and `Model.TrackAction` but neither work and I don't know what else to try.

If I debug into the code I can see the properties but just don't know what to use to get them back

Here is my partial

```
<ul id="case-studies-list" class="table">

@{
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (Asset caseStudy in caseStudies)
    {

        <li class="@(counter == 1 ? "first " : string.Empty)cell">
            <a href="@caseStudy.Url" class="track-event" data-action="@trackAction" data-label="Case Study Download" data-value="@caseStudy.Name" target="_blank">
                <span class="sprite @string.Format("case-study{0}", counter)"></span>
                <span class="text">
                    @Html.Raw(caseStudy.Name)<br />
                    <span class="font11">@Html.Raw(caseStudy.Location)</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        counter++;
    }
}

</ul>
```

This is an image of what I get when I debug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gs92.gif

Comment: Can you show _LandingPage_CaseStudiesList?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous object as model to a partial view the way you have in your question:

```
@Html.Partial("_LandingPage_CaseStudiesList", new { TrackAction = "Case Study Click", CaseStudies = "fsdffd" })
```

Then you have a couple of options in your partial view:

1. Do not declare a model in your view (i.e. do not include a statement
   like `@model MyModel` at the top)
2. Declare the model as dynamic (i.e. include a statement like `@model dynamic`)

In both cases you should be able to access your properties as in

```
@Model.TrackAction
@Model.CaseStudies
```

Also, you will not have intellisense on your view file and you will receive an exception at runtime if the property doesn't exist in the model.

Answer (score 2):

When defining your partial view you define what class it will be using as its data context. i.e:

```
@model SomeViewModel
```

MVC requires that this be a concrete type. Because of this I would suggest creating a folder in your project called `ViewModels` and creating a class to hold your information. So given your example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string TrackAction { get; set; }
    public string CaseStudies { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can then use when defining your partial view like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_LandingPage_CaseStudiesList", new MyViewModel{ TrackAction = "Case Study Click", CaseStudies = Model.CaseStudies })
```

If you don't want to use a viewmodel then I would suggest looking into other methods like ViewBags.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using an explicit model as I am using the partial on many different pages which all have different models.  It just seems weird that I am able to access the Model of the data I have passed but can't get the data out of the model

Comment: @Pete could you use an interface that all the models inherit?

Comment: @Pete: Also, the way you're passing the data right now, you're already going to all the effort of initializing a new object with this data. It wouldn't be that difficult to add the name of the class before your initializer in all these cases, would it?

Comment: @Pete if you pass anonymous types into your partial view that it depends on, you're introducing a point of failure into your application. In the future, if another developer needs to make changes to your application, they may not realize the hidden dependency you have on this anonymous type and cause unnecessary issues that will take time to diagnose. Defining a concrete model for your View will make your code more resilient and prevent situations like that.

Comment: I guess not but the problem is there are loads of different types of case study lists and I already have 2 models called case study or some other version of case study so I was just trying to avoid another case study model.  Guess that it would make it more maintainable if i had a strong typed object though

Comment: @Pete another advantage of using a ViewModel would be that in the event your CaseStudy model changes in the future, you only have to modify the ViewModel class once. If you were using anonymous objects, you would have to go through each and every view that calls it to modify what it is passing. It would be a nightmare to maintain.